# Query in Access to Retrieve the names of lecturer such that the combined enrollment of the courses that they teach is less than 5 students

Tags: windows

Retrieve the names of lecturer such that the combined enrollment of the courses that they teach is less than 5 students. There are 3 table which is enrollment (StudentID,ClassName), Class (ClassName, LecturerID), Lecturer (LecturerID, LecturerName). I need an answer in Ms Acess query. Answer in sql like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.LecturerName
FROM Lecturer L
JOIN Class C
    ON L.LecturerID = C.LecturerID
WHERE
    (SELECT count(E.ClassName)
     FROM Enrollment E
     WHERE C.ClassName = E.ClassName
     AND C.LecturerID = L.LecturerID) < 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change a bit the query and this is the answer. Thank you very much for helping me out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.LecturerName
FROM LECTURER L 
LEFT JOIN CLASS C ON L.LecturerID = C.LecturerID
WHERE(SELECT COUNT (E.StudentID) 
FROM ENROLLMENT E 
WHERE C.ClassName= E.ClassName AND C.LecturerID= L.LecturerID) < 5;
```